# its possible to use ARCore to make a complete augmented reality in android using the mostly C and NDK?

Tags: android, c, arcore

i'm  new to use ARCore (and to android programming, as i mostly did desktop asm/C/Linux/Windows/RPi stuff), and i dont really like JAVA or anything that is forcefully object oriented (as in built-in OOP features, not the general OOP concept... i.e. its fine to use COM from C for example), so that said...

its possible to use ARCore to make a complete augmented reality for android using mostly C and NDK? like using next to nothing from the java side, to the point that once you do the initial skeleton to handle the UI events, everything else, capturing/rendering/management/etc... can be done from the C side?

Comment: The `dart` language and `flutter` is the "new hotness" for Android

Comment: A quick search brings up these page: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/quickstart and https://github.com/android/ndk-samples That said should you want to use any Android API which does not have a NDK version, for example Bluetooth, you'll have to bridge between the two via JNI as the platform is built on Java APIs.

Comment: i see... well i also found that C quickstart, but ok... since it starts with "use android studio" i first have to get rid of all that to have a simple .bat/makefile to compile and not needing any of the bloatware for me to able to start, hence why i was asking so i dont want waste too much time creating a nice clean non bloated environment, for something that wouldnt work in C :)

Comment: If you're going to reject android studio, then you're trying to make this hard for yourself. You should try it before you reject it. Some of the arguments you're making would be like a Java programmer say: "I want to write C code, but I don't want to use `libc` to open files"

Comment: oh no... android studio is not windows compatible anymore... so i can't even use this thing as it does not work on 32bit... sigh... big disappointment...

Comment: so 4.0 canary 9 is the latest version that have real windows binaries, i will have to stick with that unless the 4.0+ also works on 32bit but some part of the bloat require 64bit only,  oh well, and yes i know that its make it hard.. but i dont want the bloat of having to carry around 1gb of java stuff just to compile for android instead of something simple... its the way i do stuff... i keep them simple not bloated. (and i want to have a single java skeleton and then code everything in C not touching/compiling java ever again.)

Comment: If you are on a 32-bit build system, see: https://developers.google.com/ar/64bit and https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/64-bit

Comment: oh yeah that applies to target platform thats fine... i would always have 64bit anyway if 32bit can't be run on 64bit... because i value a lot compatibility and minimum requirements... unlike almost everyone else.. that threat requirement as a "business"... it would be even nicer if they had the requirement to have both 32/64 for the supported platforms everytime... instead of just 64bit being the mandatory... which should be the defacto standard thing for all platforms that have 32/64